# Making a function work in all divs with the same class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a responsive div (.container) that contains a row of nested divs (.imgWrapper) that each contain an image (.imgWrapper img). The purpose of the following code is to make all images the same height while still fitting in one row in the container despite all images being a different proportion to one another (i.e. landscape and portrait)

```
var totalHeight = 100;
var totalWidth = 1;
$('.imgWrapper').each(function(){
totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
});

var containerWidth = $('.container').width();
var ratio = totalWidth / totalHeight;
var containerHeight = containerWidth / ratio;

$('.container').css('height',containerHeight + "px");
$('.imgWrapper img').css('height',containerHeight + "px");

var newTotalWidth = 0;
$('.imgWrapper').each(function(){
newTotalWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
});

$('.container').css('width',newTotalWidth + "px");

});

});
```

This all works great if there is only one div with the class '.container', however as soon as I add div with the same class, the function is applied to all images instead of images in each '.container' div. How to I apply this function to each '.container' div one at a time?

Here is a jsfidde example: http://jsfiddle.net/tbbeqcqb/

Comment: works fine.  I copied and pasted your container div, and i added a bunch of random images and it works.  Could you make a jsfiddle link of the problem itself?

Comment: true, i did the same and it works fine. check here http://jsfiddle.net/tbbeqcqb/1/

Comment: sorry, my mistake. jsfiddle doesn't illustrate the problem for some reason. Here is how it is supposed to be: http://www.geoffgoode.com/sample.html but here is the problem: http://www.geoffgoode.com/sample2.html -  you will notice that the images have shrunk because the combined width of all images is being calculated, not just the ones in each '.container'

Comment: does the anwser help?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but I think it's this;

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {

  var totalHeight = 100;
  $('.container').each(function(){

    var totalWidth = 1;
    $(this).children().filter('.imgWrapper').each(function(){
        totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
    });

    var containerWidth = $(this).width();
    var ratio = totalWidth / totalHeight;
    var containerHeight = containerWidth / ratio;

    $(this).css('height',containerHeight + 'px');

    var newTotalWidth = 0;
    $(this).children().filter('.imgWrapper').each(function(){
      $(this).children('img').css('height',containerHeight + 'px');
      newTotalWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
    });

    $(this).css('width',newTotalWidth + 'px');
  });
});
```